# how to go back to previous activity without re-rendering it

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a main activity that forks a second activity, I wanted to go back from second activity to the main activity without reinitialize it. In other words, I wanted to immediately show the main activity after second activity disappears, instead of re-rendering the first activity.  I have tried methods like **finish**, **onBackPressed**, none of this goes back directly achieved the effect I desired. Rather it seems that they go back and re-render the activity , which feels like all your previous data that renders the view is lost, and it has to do it from scratch again.

So How can I go back directly without re-rendering again?

Thanks

----------------------Update--------------------

```
Clase MainActivity extends Activity{
    public onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
           super.onCreate(SaveInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.mainview);
           GoogleMap gmap = ...
           Route route = ...
           //draw a route in the google map
           // now the map bears a route on it
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondActivity.class)

   }

}

Class SecondActivity extends Activity{
    public onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondview);

        Button backbut =(Button) findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
    }
    //backbut is associated with a call back onClick in the xml
    private onClick(View){
        finish();//after this the second activity disappears, but previously drawn route on google map also disappears, and it takes time to redraw them again. feels like onCreate in firstActivity is reentered again
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get call for your mainActivity in OnNewIntent() ,it doesnt reinitialize ur activity...instead u get a call in this callback..

Comment: Post you first Activity to second activity go code..

Comment: finish() will work, show me code what you are doing, that will help to suggest something to you

Comment: please check my updated code scratch to have a clearer idea of what I am doing

Comment: Strange thing is that, I can go back without re-rendering by pressing android's back button on the phone, but can't do so by pressing my button

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this two flag to accomplish what you want:--

```
   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

Just use this code:--

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,
                MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not call finish() on going second activity then the first activity is running on background and after calling finish() on second activity the first activity appears without re-initialize as privious state.

Answer (score 0):

Hop this will help you.

```
MainActivity extends Activity{

Context context;

      oncreate(){
          context = this;

      Intent intent = new Intent (context , SecondActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);

      /* here finish() method is not called, if called MaintActivity objects will destory*/

     }
}
```

Comment: Above code does't finished the MainActivity so it's on stack. If you finished the SecondActivity then MainActivity will call from stack. So, onCreate() method never called only onResume() will call on MainActivity. How do you saying all data's are re-rendering.?? could u pls explain it..

Answer (score 0):

Guys thank you all for your kind help! I think I kinda solved my problem. They key is that I made the onClick method private so my xml cannot find my onClick and issues an Exception, which caused activity to destroy and re-render themselves. Hope this explanation makes sense